# Is using a dictionary of lambda functions an acceptable way to write code?

Tags: python, lambda

I wanted to code a function that returns the number of days of a given month on a given year (for Project Euler 19). Of course it's very easy to do this with if statements but, for the sheer pleasure of seeing such a way work in Python, I decided to use a dictionary with lambda-functions as values:

```
md={
    'jan':lambda y: 31,
    'feb':lambda y: 29 if ((y%400 == 0) or (y%4==0 and y%100)) else 28,
    'mar':lambda y: 31,
    'apr':lambda y: 30,
    'may':lambda y: 31,
    'jun':lambda y: 30,
    'jul':lambda y: 31,
    'aug':lambda y: 31,
    'sep':lambda y: 30,
    'oct':lambda y: 31,
    'nov':lambda y: 30,
    'dec':lambda y: 31
    }

def mdays(month, year):
    return md[month](year)
```

This works perfectly.

Now I'm wondering whether there are factual reasons why this would not be recommended, compared to for example a simple function with if statements.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: a dictionary of functions would be perfectly acceptable, but that is not what you have here. Rather, you have a dictionary of *strings*. There are only strings in your dictionary. Why didn't you just use a function? Then, no need for `eval` (which is *almost always* not what you should use)

Comment: You're right, they're strings and not functions. That said, in my mind the fundamental idea is the same. By the way, how would I write a dictionary of functions in the actual sense ?

Comment: *just remove the quotation marks*. `lambda x: x + 1` is a function, `"lambda x: x + 1"` is a string. Just in general, *avoid `eval`*. Functions are *just objects*, like any other. You can use then just like `list` objects or `int` objects etc etc. Don't write out a string just to dynamically `eval` it.

Comment: I had actually first tried that, and it didn't work so I gave up (and now I realize it was a syntax error: I had forgotten the "else" part of the 'feb' lambda...). Thanks, I'll update my code and edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the strings so you don't have to eval it:

```py
md = {
    'jan': lambda y: 31,
    'feb': lambda y: 29 if ((y % 400 == 0) or (y % 4 == 0 and y % 100)) else 28,
    'mar': lambda y: 31,
    'apr': lambda y: 30,
    'may': lambda y: 31,
    'jun': lambda y: 30,
    'jul': lambda y: 31,
    'aug': lambda y: 31,
    'sep': lambda y: 30,
    'oct': lambda y: 31,
    'nov': lambda y: 30,
    'dec': lambda y: 31
}


def mdays(month, year):
    return md[month](year)

print(mdays('feb', 2400))
```

Previous comment:
Definitely not, when there's such a simple way to do this:

```py
>>> from calendar import monthrange
>>> monthrange(2011, 2)
(1, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really my point: I don't need other/simpler ways to do what I want, but insights on the method I used.

Comment: I've edited the answer to more accurately answer it then :)

Comment: Oh, stupid me, I had first tried that and it didn't work, so I thought is wasn't possible. And now I realize it was a syntax problem (I has forgotten the "else" part of the if statement)... I'll modify my code and the question.